# Git not showing files with <<<<<<< HEAD (conflicts)

Tags: git

Apologies if this can't be debugged based on the info given, but I'm really scratching my head right now.

I did a merge a while ago and now noticed that some files have `<<<<<<< HEAD` in them, like below.

```
          <script>
            function() {
            .
            .
            .
<<<<<<< HEAD
          </script>
          <script>
            .
            .
            .
            return false;
          }
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

I know that these are conflict markers and would be happy to resolve these conflicts even manually, but have no idea about all the files that might be affected as when I type `git status` I get

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

`git mergetool` yields

```
This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff
No files need merging
```

ultimately saying `No files need merging`.

What else could I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody has committed files with the conflict markers. You can:

- `git grep '<<<<'` to find files which contain the lines, then fix those manually.
- `git blame` on them and find who has committed the lines, and make sure they aware that they should first resolve commits, then mark the file as resolved.